# elasticsearch NEST (c#) Querying - matching all Elements of a dynamic List

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am new with elastic NEST and am stuggling to migrate my LINQ Querys with NEST fluent API. I have the following scenario:

I have 3 Lists and want to do an unstructured search to find the elements in this Lists. Size of the Lists is variing dynamically.
What i need:

```
List<string> listA = new List {"access", "about", "after"} 
List<string> ListB = new List {"bank", "book", "baby"}   
List<string> ListC = new List {"cake", "calf", "candy"}

"query"  : "(access OR about OR after) AND (bank OR book OR baby) AND (cake AND calf AND candy)"
```

How can i run this search at the best?

my solution until now with NEST is to concatinate all the possible key combination and then make a run for each combination. f.e. "access bank cake calf candy", "access book cake calf candy", etc.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Comment>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
         .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.CommentText)
            .Query("access bank cake calf candy")
         )
    )
);
```

i need to return a List.

Greets

Comment: For combining queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html#combining-queries

Comment: @RussCam thanks for the link but i need to combine the querys dynamically based on lenght of my Lists. I have also tried with a List of Query Objects but then o don't know how to combine them with && dynamically through Nest.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include what you have tried so far?